# Outputting csv rows in Jina for loop shows "<csv.reader object at 0x1258830>"

Tags: python, csv, flask

I'm trying to read some CSV data into an HTML Page with flask. I can probably explain what I'm trying to do better in Python than in English:

```
@app.route('/ausgabe', methods=['POST'])
def ausgabe():
with open('timetable.csv', 'rb') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(open("timetable.csv", "rb"), delimiter=",", quotechar='"')

  return render_template('zeiterfassung.html',
                                    msg="Deine Daten wurden gespeichert!",
                                    reader=reader)
```

So that was my "views.py"-file.

Now my HTML file:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
{{msg}}
  <h1>Uhrzeit</h1>
    <p>Geben sie die Uhrzeiten ein:</p><br>
    <form action="/ausgabe" method="post" >
    <label for="von">Wann bist du gekommen?</label>
    <input id="von" input type="time" name="anfangtime" placeholder="23:59"><br>
    <label for="bis">Bis wann hast du gearbeitet?</label>
    <input id="bis" input type="time" name="bistime" placeholder="23:59"><br>
    <button type="submit" name="save" value="0">Speichern</button>
    </form>
        {% for row in reader %}
            {{reader}}
        {% endfor %}    

{% endblock %}
```

So if I visit "/ausgabe" with a browser it tells me:

> < csv.reader object at 0x1258830>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect you mean `{{ row }}` inside the for loop.

Plus, you don't need to open the CSV twice:

```
with open('timetable.csv', 'rb') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",", quotechar='"')
```